# How to use IF in MS Excel for getting specific column value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a diseases dataset saved in MS Excel sheet, the format of the data is given below:

`| Object Name | Symptom 1 | Symptom 2 | Symptom 3 |...| Symptom N | Disease |
 |      ABC    |     1     |     0     |     0     |...|     n     |    XYZ  |
 |      ABC    |     0     |     1     |     0     |...|     n     |    XYZ  |
 |      ABC    |     1     |     0     |     1     |...|     n     |    YZX  |
 |      ABC    |     1     |     1     |     0     |...|     n     |    XYZ  |`

where the first column is entering variable i.e name of some object and the leaving column i.e. last column is a disease name. The columns in between are the symptoms columns for the specific disease of that object.

Now, for each row in the sheet, I want to get all the symptoms attribute where the value is 1, i.e. this symptom is present, using Disease column as a decision variable. Logic is given below.

```
for each row in the sheet 
  -->  IF (Disease = XYZ)
  --> Get all the Symptoms variables where value is 1
```

The desired result for the first rows is as follow;

> Row 1 --> XYZ (Symptom1) 
>     Row 2 --> XYZ (Symptom2) 
>     Row 3 --> XYZ (Symptom1, Symptom3) 
>     Row 4 --> XYZ (Symptom1, Symptom2)

How can I do this in MS Excel, using IF formula? Help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Use a filter. In a filter you can use logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can afford a spare empty worksheet, here is an example.
Let `Sheet1` be the main worksheet and `Sheet2` is an empty one;
the titles of the symptoms are in `Sheet1!$C$4:$F$4`, 
the flags in `Sheet1!C5:F8`.

Type

```
=B5&IF(Sheet1!C5,","&Sheet1!C$4,"")
```

into cell `C5`  on the `Sheet2` 
and then copy this cell to fill the block `Sheet2!C5:F8`.
The last column (`Sheet2!F5:F8`) will contain the lists of symptoms per row 
(with an extra comma in front).

[image]

Then just add the formula

```
=G5&"("&REPLACE(Sheet2!F5,1,1,"")&")"
```

into cell `Sheet1!H5` on the `Sheet1` and copy it down the column.

[image]

If your database is too big, and such a waste is not an option, then consider 
to use [VBA function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135995/how-to-merge-rows-in-a-column-into-one-cell-in-excel)
with appropriate modifications.

**Edit:**

Some suggestions:

If it works OK with ~2000 records 
but can't handle the whole size,
then at least you can split it in chunks.

VBA solution is also a possible alternative.

One more (OT) alternative could be to use [Gnumeric](http://www.gnumeric.org/).
It can read/write `excel` files, 
and its `concatenate` function can handle ranges properly, 
so there is a one-cell formula solution for the OP.

There is also a possibility to create a custom `excel Add-on`,
but it seems this would be an overkill in this case.

Comment: My dataset is quite big but I don't know much about the use of VBA function, the link that you have provided. Why this method isn't good for large dataset?

Comment: @Muhammad Toseef: This approach uses a lot more memory, but
there are too many factors to decide will it work or not.
The main are: the size of the database,
the amount of RAM available, CPU, etc.
Just use a copy of your data to check if it works OK.

Comment: it works for now. Great solution. Though I tested it for almost 2000 records, but my data is coming and I'll be ending up in huge amount of data. Can you kindly suggest that what other approach will be helpful for this operation?

Comment: @Muhammad Toseef: some suggestions added.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use an IF(AND function. I wrote up the following:
=IF(AND(H32=1,I32=1,J32=1),K32,"No Disease")

H32,I32,J32 all had a 1 or a 0 in it. K32 was the 'disease'.

You could also do something like this:

=IF(H32+I32+J32=3,K32,K33)

k33 was 'no disease', while the other cells were the same as the above.

Does that help?